# Preg_Replace links in a text like facebook

Tags: php, hyperlink, preg-replace, meta-tags

**How can I convert a link in a text:**
 sdgf  sdg  https://www.google.ch/  dgsd  dfg

**Into this:** 
Click [here](http://666kb.com/i/d0nb0t6kzrajd71f1.jpg) to view the image

Similar to Facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$result = preg_replace('/<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', "\\2", $string);
```

Comment: No I want it like facebook with the meta tags of the website